# Equivalence to the usage of process substitution?

Tags: bash, process-substitution

Is the usage of process substitution

```
command1 <(command2)
```

equivalent to

```
command2 > ~/myfile
command1 ~myfile
```

?

Can the two above be replaced with each other?

Does `command1` and `command2` in the usage of command substitution always run simultaneously, while in the "replacement" `command1` runs only after `command2` finishes running?

If yes, does this difference make the two not equivalent and not always replaced with each other in some cases?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

This is [process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html).

The end result of both forms you give should be mostly the same; the differences are that

- as you point out, process substitution runs both processes simultaneously;
- your second form uses a file on a file system, so you need space to store that (and ideally, remove it afterwards).

Technically, the I/O between processes involving process substitution behaves like pipes, not like files. (This might well be an implementation detail though.)

Correctly-written programs shouldn’t exhibit differences in their *results* because they run simultaneously; for example,

```
tail -n 1 <(seq 1 10000000)
```

correctly shows the last number in the sequence, whereas attempting to do this manually with

```
seq 1 10000000 > blah &
tail -n 1 blah
```

will fail because `tail` shows whatever is the last line stored at the time it runs, it doesn’t wait for `seq` to finish. Your second form correctly waits in this instance.

You can however see differences in external *behaviour*. For example,

```
head -n 1 <(seq 1 1000000000)
```

finishes immediately (even `seq`, thanks to the pipe behaviour), whereas

```
seq 1 1000000000 > blah
head -n 1 blah
```

takes quite a long time to run. This type of difference can mean that replacing one form with the other isn’t appropriate.

Comment: I've never looked into the source to see which `bash` prefers to use, but the man page documents process substitution as requiring either named pipes or `/dev/fd`.